# Can we create an exception class in c# which can infer the type of exception and show the relevant info accordingly?

Tags: c#, exception

I have heard and read that we need to know in `Code time` what exceptions we are going to be confronted with and place the necessary catches.

Now cant we infer the type of the actual exception that has just happened from the `Exception` class and then cast that and get the needed info? 
for example consider this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                //try doing something to generate and exception
                int blah =8 / Convert.ToInt32(txtBox.Text);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //ex.GetType().Name
                //getting the type and casting it according to the retrieved name
                //and finally showing the more detailed info of the occurred exception
               //for example like this?
               //MessageBox((ex.GetType())ex).Message);  
            }
        }
```

This is just a sample to convey my meaning, suppose if that is possible we make that a custom class which inherits from `Exception` and do the needed work for such a purpose.

Cant we do such a thing? If we can how can we cast it ? and if it cant be done why is that?

Comment: I don't see how this would be different than creating specific catches for specific exceptions. Except that it'd be a mess to code.

Comment: The reason is that maybe i have no clue what kind of exceptions even exists for the section im coding for, using this i would understand and code accordingly.
@Selman22: Thats just an example, getting the actual type is what matters since it has detailed information compared to the general Exception class i believe.

Comment: @Hossein, it is possible with reflection,just get your type,and properties then get property values and display whatever you want

Comment: Just use a catch for `Exception` at the end, and use `ToString()` and/or `Message`. You don't get anything different from those with descendant classes. If you did, that would violate polymorphism.

Comment: What you call "code time" is more often referred to as "compile time" or "link time". Plus, there's no such thing as "costume class" (unless you're programming some kind of freaky party app) :p They are called "custom classes".

Comment: @selman22's above comment is also good.

Comment: @LeandroTaset I wish I'd had those classes in school ;)

Comment: if the descendant classes doesnt get me more detailed info, why are they present in frist place? doesnt this render them kind of useless? since everything is already present in Exception class itself!? Im confused!
@Selman22: I would appreciate a sample if possible

Comment: I know about polymorphism, i just dont get it why would using a base class and then cast accordingly to get the needed info instead of hard-coding everything?
This is undoubtedly correct to use specific exception types for specific parts, what i am trying is to avoid hard coding everything and making it more dynamic.

Comment: System.Exception *is* the base class that you are essentially thinking of re-writing.  You want to know at compile time which exceptions you can reasonably handle.  If you get an exception that you are not expecting (and explicitly catching), you will probably want the system to actually throw that exception, as you don't know how to handle it.  Now, there is nothing to say that you can't use some static (global) methods to handle exceptions that you catch, if you need to handle them the same way in all cases.

Answer (score 2):

If you want, you can **delegate exception handling** logic to some *well-defined module*, whose purpose is to... handle exceptions :) Maybe this way...?

```
try {
    // code that throws something
} catch (Exception e) {
    myExceptionHandlingStrategy.handleException(e);
}
```

where *myExceptionHandlingStrategy* is an instance of **MyExceptionHandlingStrategy**, a module that exposes the interface **IExceptionHandlingStrategy**, defined (probably) as follows:

```
interface IExceptionHandlingStrategy {
    void handleException(Exception e);
}
```

Then, in certain implementations of that interface (you may have a lot of them), you are free to do something like this:

```
if (e is SomethingBadException) {
    // show some message
} else if (e is SomeOtherKindOfException) {
    // do something else instead
} else {
    throw new CannotHandleThisException(e);
}
```

PS: **NO** reflection :)

Comment: This is incomplete and basically achieves nothing except effectively swallowing the exception and also moving the main handling logic to some other place (which, in turn, would make it harder to maintain in the future).

Comment: @LeandroTaset, I forgot to thank you for pointing that out :) Though, usually, logic **delegation** & module **segregation** do not make some piece of software "harder to maintain in the future" - we simply move the **catch** part somewhere else - that method is becoming shorter, easier to read and so on...

Comment: Hi, @andrei. Better :) Please, refer to my answer below for a more detailed explanation of what I meant. Plus, I agree with you: logic delegation & module segregation do not make some piece of software "harder to maintain in the future". Usually! Thanks to you too.

Answer (score 2):

To give an example of Chris Cudmore's suggestion

```
        try
        {

        }
        catch (System.FormatException FormatEx)
        {
            //logic here
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //generic catch-all
            MessageBox(ex.Message);
            throw;
        }
```

Most of the time, you want to know the type of exception before hand so you can handle that exception specifically (for any cleanup/recovery tasks), not so you can access base members such as `Exception.Message`.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer to your question is: **yes, of course** (kind of). A more meaningful answer would go through all the pain of trying to explain how to do proper exception handling. There's close to an infinite number of articles on the web about this subject, plus a handful of practical valuable (and pricey) books for that matter. A question in SO could set you in the right direction, but nothing more.

Your sample code is quite trivial, as is the norm for examples. The ugly truth is you almost never face so simple problems in day to day software development. So, it is difficult to make a story and illustrate a somewhat complex idea over a simplistic and specific case. There have been many attempts at solving what you allude in your question, like the [Exception Handling Application Block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650741.aspx), for instance.

But there's an essential difference between handling an exception to take note of its existence for letting a user/developer know exactly what is wrong in an application, and on the other hand handling exceptions to do some kind of unorthodox control of a program's execution flow.

Swallowing an exception is unacceptable under almost every circumstance. There's quite a limited number of exceptions (pun intended) to that rule. You should catch exceptions only when you can recover from the error without negatively affecting the utter flow of the program, not just because you want to "handle" them. That's basically the reason why I disagreed with the solutions given by @martin-lariviere and @andrei.

When you catch an exception and don't handle it well, you might be inadvertently affecting the called method's postconditions, which might indirectly affect the calling code's execution because of unmet assumptions made about the called piece of logic. In turn, all that could lead to an unstable state of the program. In short: a latent demon lurking around ready to bite you in any moment, eager to corrupt some data (at least).

The sample method is `void`, but what if it were something else? What if an exception occurred in the middle of an operation needed to determine some return value? How would you handle such exception? You have basically two options:

- (*Dangerous*) Swallow the exception, use some default value for the calculation and return a potentially inaccurate result that might "astonish" the calling code (and the user). Even in this situation, it would be wise to log the error at least. Your "future you" might be thankful someday if he had to trace a bug caused by this particular misbehaviour. It might be safe, but that would depend on the particular method being implemented (specifically its postconditions and invariants).
- (*Delicate*) Allow the exception to propagate to the calling code; either "as is" or wrapped in some other exception. In this situation you might log the error, but it's not really necessary. Nevertheless, you might take action to ensure that some resources are properly released and maybe some half-initialized objects or mid-modified data goes back to some stable state again.

Either option requires that sensible judgment calls be taken to implement a proper exception handling strategy, and that should be considered for every operation that might throw an exception! Obviously, it's something every developer should take into account every time they type any code. It's brutal.

So, there's no easy *correct* answer to your question. Maybe you want a pattern to solve once and for all the things to do in the second option (*Delicate*). Sadly, there's none. Maybe in a second post I could elaborate on that: error conditions, exceptions and notifications/alerts to the user in the UI. That is a tough subject, and this "answer" is already awfully verbose.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is not necessary but here is an example:

```
try
{
    int[] numbers = new int[2];

    numbers[6] = 345;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
      Type t = ex.GetType();

      var props = t.GetProperties();

      foreach (var p in props)
      {
          Console.WriteLine(p.Name + " : " + p.GetValue(ex));
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your intentions are.
Your `ex` variable should hold the error messages generated along with the list of the inner ones.
If you want to have the name of the type you can do the following :

```
catch (System.Exception _ex)
{
    switch (_ex.GetType().FullName)
    {
        case "System.FormatException":
            *//Do what you want in case of a FormatException error...*
            break;
        case "System.*other type*":
            *//Do what you want in case of a ...*
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
 }
```

Comment: Why not just catch(System.FormatException _fEx) and catch the remainder below?